# Sklearn CountVectorizer "Empty Vocabulary" error in Dataframe when computing nGram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have a dataframe (`data`) with 3 records:

```
id    text
0001  The farmer plants grain
0002  The fisher catches tuna
0003  The police officer fights crime
```

I group that dataframe by id:

```
data_grouped = data.groupby('id')
```

Describing the resulting groupby object shows that all the records remain.

I then run this code to find the nGrams in the `text` and join them to the `id`:

```
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, ngram_range=(2,2), 
analyzer='word')
for id, group in data_grouped:
       X = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(group['text'])
       frequencies = sum(X).toarray()[0]
       results = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, columns=['frequency'])
       dfinner = pd.DataFrame(word_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
       dfinner['id'] = id
       final = results.join(dfinner)
```

When I run all of this code together, an error kicks out for the `word_vectorizer` that states "empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words". I know this error has been mentioned in many other questions, but I couldn't find one that deals with a Dataframe.

To further complicate the issue, the error doesn't always show up. I am pulling the data from a SQL DB, and depending on how many records I pull in, the error may or may not show up. For instance, pulling in `Top 10` records causes the error, but `Top 5` doesn't.

EDIT:

Complete Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-63-d261e44b8cce>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/taca/Documents/Work/Python/Text Analytics/owccomments.py', wdir='C:/Users/taca/Documents/Work/Python/Text Analytics')

  File "C:\Users\taca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\taca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/taca/Documents/Work/Python/Text Analytics/owccomments.py", line 38, in <module>
    X = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(group['cleanComments'])

  File "C:\Users\taca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 839, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)

  File "C:\Users\taca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 781, in _count_vocab
    raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only"

ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What do you mean when you say "When I run all of this code together"? Also post the complete stack trace of error.

Comment: See my edit for the traceback. I also tried to change `X = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(group['cleanComments'])` to `X = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(data['cleanComments'])` which got rid of the error but...obviously it lost the grouping also, so every nGram was being assigned to every `id`.

Also, when I add `print(final)` to the loop, the output prints out as I expect with dataframes for each `id` contianing only the nGrams for that `id`

Comment: Disregard my comment about "running the code all together", I just meant when I execute the script, this error occurs.

Comment: It appears like it may be hanging up when the dataframe includes a row that doesn't have a bigram (i.e. only has one word). Is there a way to put another loop inside the for loop that says something along the lines of `if group['text'] includes less than 1 word` then ignore? I'm just not sure how to write that in Python.

Comment: Or, better yet, would there be a way to include the unigrams if group['text'] only has one word?

Answer (score 2):

I see what is going on here, but in running through it I have a nagging question. **Why are you doing this?** I'm not quite sure I understand the value of fitting the CountVectorizer to each document in a collection of documents. Generally the idea is to fit it to the entire corpus and then do you analysis from there. I get that maybe you want to be able to see what grams exist in each document but there are other, much easier and optimized, ways of doing this. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'text': ['The farmer plants grain', 'The fisher catches tuna', 'The police officer fights crime']})
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
dt_mat = cv.fit_transform(df.text)
print(cv.get_feature_names())
['catches tuna',
 'farmer plants',
 'fights crime',
 'fisher catches',
 'officer fights',
 'plants grain',
 'police officer',
 'the farmer',
 'the fisher',
 'the police']
print(dt_mat.todense())
[[0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1]]
```

Great so there you can see the features extracted by the CountVectorizer and the matrix representation of what features exist in each document. `dt_mat` is the Document Term Matrix and represents the count of each gram (the frequency) in the vocabulary (the features) for each document. To map this back to the grams, and even place it into your DataFrame you can do the following:

```
df['grams'] = cv.inverse_transform(dt_mat)
print(df)
   id                             text  \
0   1          The farmer plants grain
1   2          The fisher catches tuna
2   3  The police officer fights crime

                                               grams
0          [plants grain, farmer plants, the farmer]
1         [catches tuna, fisher catches, the fisher]
2  [fights crime, officer fights, police officer,...
```

Personally this feels more meaningful, because you are fitting the CountVectorizer to the entire corpus and not just a single document at a time. You can still extract the same information (the frequency and the grams) and this will be much faster as you scale up in documents.

Comment: Thank you very much - I really like this idea. The reason I was thinking I should do it per document is because the results will eventually have to be fed back into a relational database, and having the nGrams stuffed into one line (or in separate columns) doesn't seem like it would work well in that scenario.

Comment: I've implemented your method, and I got the dataframe back into my DB. However, I'm struggling with how to group by id and get the frequencies of each ngram (and later the tf-idf score of each ngram) back into the dataframe. How would I accomplish that?